# How to I fetch Drop Down Items from Database into PHP select drop down form field

Tags: php, mysql

Please how do i populate select dropdown list directly from Database table colunm?

Looking forward to your answers.
Thanks

```
<?php 
include('header.php');
include('server.php');//DB Connection
?>

<div class="form-group">
 <label>Select Center</label>
            <?php
                echo "<select class='form-control' name='center'>";
                $result = mysqli_query("SELECT center_name FROM center");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    unset($center);
                    $center = $row['center']; 
                    echo '<option value="'.$center.'"></option>';

                    }

                    echo "</select>";
            ?>
</div>
<div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Your column name in SQL is `center_name` but you're using `$row['center']` in your loop

Comment: The center_name is the column field name in DB. Could it really be??? Let me change that. Thanks for quick response.

Comment: Well then change the key name in the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have used column name `center_name` but under loop you put `center` as array key

Change

```
$center = $row['center'];
```

to

```
$center = $row['center_name'];
```

And you have set option values but you forgot to add your php variable inside option tag

```
echo '<option value="'.$center.'">'. $center .'</option>';
```

Comment: I have changed the Key from 'center' to 'center_name', Yet, still didn't run. More help please!!!

Comment: This is the variable declare. I don't know maybe something could wrong there.  $centerError ="";
        $center = "";

Comment: @Laolu Aladejana I have updated my answer. You can check

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I resolved the issue by viewing the HTML sourescode through the browser and discovered an error message in the viewsource on browser which did not display to me.

The solution was that i just passed the Database connection as $con as second parameter into the mysqli_query() and that solved the problem.

Thanks all.
    `<div class="form-group">
                             <label>Select Center</label>
                                        <select class='form-control' name='center_name'><br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\soap\create_user.php</b> on line <b>141</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\soap\create_user.php</b> on line <b>143</b><br />
</select>

                            </div>
                            <div>`